# Print a link based on the taxonomy term or id in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a list of links on `page.tpl.php` and I would like to have one link display on nodes that is using one taxonomy term id. The taxonomy term id is 9.

Ex.

```
<ul class="top-menu-new upper-menu-new">
<li> <a>NEWS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;  </li>
<li> <a href="">BLOG</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;  </li>
<li> <a href="">FAQ</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>

<?php if the node is using taxonomy term id 9
<li><a href=">PRIVATE PAGE</a> </li>
<?php else: ?>
<li><a href="">PUBLIC PAGE</a> </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Drupal has various ways to control access to specific pages, I'm not sure using taxonomy is the best way to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's `template.php`; Using [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)(), your code should look like that

```
function [YOUR_THEME]_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
    if(isset($vars['node']))
    {
        $node = $vars['node'];
        $nodeLanguage = "und"; // or use any language
        if(isset($node->field_YOUR_FIELD_REFERENCE[$nodeLanguage]))
        {
            foreach($node->field_YOUR_FIELD[$nodeLanguage] as $key => $val)
            {
                if($val['tid'] == "9")
                    $vars['found_my_term'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your page template `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php if($found_my_term) { ?>
<li><a href=">PRIVATE PAGE</a> </li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><a href="">PUBLIC PAGE</a> </li>
<?php } ?>
```

The code is about checking if the current page is a `node page`, then checks if the `node has your taxonomy field reference` (In this code sample I used `field_YOUR_FIELD_REFERENCE` as the field name), and at last checks if it has a value of `9`.

And if so, you are storing the result in a variable (I called `found_my_term`) so you can use in your page templates.

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad Reda. Your understanding is correct. I tried your code but for some reason, it's only showing the "PUBLIC PAGE". Note I corrected the missing " in link for PRIVATE PAGE. I'm not sure of the term ID but this is the screenshot of that term - http://screencast.com/t/1eZ3i0ew. I maybe wrong? basically the term "Private Partner" has /content/private/* in the URL while the "PUBLIC PAGE" don't. Thank you again!

Comment: @liza; The code above will show the link to `PRIVATE PAGE` only if your are on taxonomy term 9 page `YOUR_SITE_URL/taxonomy/term/9`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I placed the wrong instructions. I would like to actually have the link "PRIVATE PAGE" display on all pages that are using the taxonomy term "Partner Private" and display "PUBLIC PAGE" if it's not. Can you still help me with that? I'm no good in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Muhammad Reda. For some reason, I'm getting this error "Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in page.tpl.php"

Comment: Thanks again Your changes removed the error but unfortunately, the code is not working as expected. It's only showing PUBLIC PAGE across the site. I already cleared the system's cache. By the way, I'm using D7.

Comment: Hi again. I think I missed this part - "field_YOUR_FIELD_REFERENCE", not sure what to put here... is this "PARTNER PRIVATE" or taxonomy term?

Comment: The name of the field that is linking the node with the taxonomy term.

Comment: i see. I'll hand your code now to one of our programmers. Thanks again Muhammad!